# Adding external source files to a kotlin project

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

I have Kotlin sources located at, say, `repo/project_a/src/`. I created a Kotlin Gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA, located at `repo/project_b/...`. And I can't for the life of me figure out how to add the sources. If I add them through project structure menu it works fine, but as soon as it wants to re-read the gradle file id deletes the structure (It warns as much in the UI).

This is my gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.2.70'
}

group 'cli'
version '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

I've tried adding all variations of

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        kotlin {
            srcDirs += "repo/project_a/"
        }
    }
}
```

But it does absolutely nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: `main.kotlin.srcDirs` should work. Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CrazyCoder - What's incomplete about my example? I created a new project in intellij idea, the gradle file above is the entire gradle file, and I just need to figure out how to add another directory to it. I'm not sure what else I can provide at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path you are giving to Gradle will compile to the current project path plus "repo/project_a/". Try with:

```
sourceSets { 
    main { 
         kotlin { 
              srcDirs += "../project_a/" 
          }
       }
  }
```

Comment: When I was testing, I tried full paths as well; without any luck. I haven't tried relative paths, so I will report back how that goes.

Comment: So, apparently the sourceSets doesn't like ~ paths, and also if there's  another gradle configuration in there somewhere, it may confuse the build.